# Is it possible to simplify $ \sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\arctan x\right)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Is it possible to simplify the expressions
$$
\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\arctan x\right)
$$
and
$$
\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\arctan x\right)?
$$
My idea was to make use of the double angle formulae to reexpress the above expressions as e.g.
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\sin\left(\arctan x\right)=2\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\arctan x\right)
\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\arctan x\right),
$$
and similarly for $\cos\left(\arctan x\right)$, but I haven't been able to solve for $
\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\arctan x\right)$ or $
\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\arctan x\right)$.

Comment: As a practical note, $\sin(\frac 12\arctan(x))$ is not much different from $\alpha\arctan(x)$ with some $\alpha$ slightly less than $\frac 12$ (approx 0.46). This may be of interest if you call for approximation instead of exact value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $$\sin^2\Bigl({x\over 2}\Bigr) = {1-\cos(x)\over 2}$$ to get rid of the one-half.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin^2\Bigl({\theta\over 2}\Bigr) = {1-\cos(\theta)\over 2}$$
$$\sin^2\Bigl({\arctan(x)\over 2}\Bigr) = {1-\cos(\arctan(x))\over 2}={1-{1\over \sqrt{1+x^2}}\over 2}$$

By the way, $\sin(\arctan(x))={x\over \sqrt{1+x^2}}$, not ${1\over \sqrt{1+x^2}}$